# Microsoft Surface pro Tablet windows 8 Language set up

Tags: windows-8, language

purchased Microsoft Surface pro tablet Windows 8 that says Spanish, Portuguese, Italian ONLY.  Does this mean when i start widows on the set up screen, windows will only give me these 3 language options to choose from?  In other words I don't have the option to choose English?  (Haven't opened and started the set up so thats why asking these questions)  (obvious answer will be to open and start up the windows and see it for myself but was wondering if someone out there might know).

if it does only give me these 3 language to choose from, is there any possibility to install English later on to windows 8 for microsoft surface pro tablet?  if so do i purchase it through windows online? thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: 90% English should be available - I'm guessing too

Comment: OEMs customize the Images for several markets and your was for southerns Europe. Install the English MUI later via controlpanel-> languages.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean when i start widows on the set up screen, windows will
>   only give me these 3 language options to choose from?

At least until you install an additional language pack

Comment: thank you!  the set up screen still gave me English as the option so no problem afterwards!